# Dúvidas sobre uso de funções em C

Tags: c, string, funções

Preciso fazer um exercício que, basicamente, pedirá ao usuário que digite duas strings. Antes disso, é informado um valor inteiro X representando a posição a partir da qual a primeira string será gravada na variável que a armazenará e só então digita-se as duas strings. Em seguida, uma função coloca a segunda string na posição em que a primeira string foi recebida.

Minhas duvidas são:

1 - Para criar um arquivo separado para chamar a função, preciso usar alguma biblioteca? Estava dando erro quando tentei por conta;

2 - Ao utilizar a função no mesmo arquivo de `main()`, estou recebendo os
    seguintes avisos e o código não está rodando:

```
warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]

passing argument 2 of 'trocarPosicao' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

warning: passing argument 3 of 'trocarPosicao' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int'
```

Segue meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void trocarPosicao (int posicao , char a[posicao] , char b[0]);


 int main() {

    int posicao;
    char a[10] , b[10];



    printf("Digite uma posição para o primeiro nome:");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &posicao);
    printf("Digite um nome: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%s" , &a[posicao]);
    printf("Digite outro nome: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%s" , b[0]);

    trocarPosicao(posicao , a[posicao] , b[0]);
}

 void trocarPosicao (int posicao , char a[posicao] , char b[0]) {

  a[posicao] = b[0];

  printf("Primeiro nome : %s", a[posicao]);
  printf("Segundo nome: %s" , b[0]);
  printf("Posição: %d ", posicao);

 }
```

Comment: Você tem certeza de que é para colocar a segunda na posição da primeira? Parece ser na verdade outro problema: colocar a segunda string na posição subseqüente à primeira. Caso contrário, não faz muito sentido didaticamente. Seria interessante revisar o texto.

Comment: Essa é a questão: Escrever uma função que receba como parâmetro duas strings, bem como um valor
inteiro que representa uma posição. A função deve, portanto, inserir a segunda string no
na posição indicada da primeira.
Escreva um programa que receba estas duas strings do usuário, o valor da posição
desejada, e chame a função anteriormente implementada e exiba o resultado ao usuário
na tela.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "Para criar um arquivo separado para chamar a função"? Para chamar uma função você não precisa de arquivo nenhum. É possível definir o fonte de uma função em um arquivo diferente e no processo de compilação juntar os objetos. Sua definição dos parâmetros da função estão estranhos. Talvez devesse ser: void trocarPosicao (int posicao , char a[] , char b[]);

Comment: E como faço pra definir a fonte de uma função? pq vi uns comentarios na internet e precisava colocar um #include e o nome do arquivo. E estou bastante confuso com essa questão também, é um exercicio de um trabalho, mas parece estar um pouco mal formulada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito esse exercício, mas a maioria dos erros no seu código são referentes a manipulação de arrays.

As variáveis utilizadas para armazenar strings `a` e `b`, são arrays de `char`. O valor contido em `a` e `b` é um ponteiro para a primeira posição desses arrays, `a` e `b` são ponteiros mas os valores contidos em `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]` são do tipo `char`.

Quando você faz algo do tipo `scanf("%s", b[0])`, você está dizendo para o programa colocar a entrada do usuário, que é um array de caracteres, no index `0` de `b`, mas o index `0` de `b` contém apenas um caractere, como um único `char` irá armazenar um array de `char`?

Por outro lado quando você utiliza `scanf("%s", &a[posicao])`, você está passando o endereço de memória de `a[posicao]` para o `scanf`, essa posição de memória é do tipo `char*`. Isso é válido, mas qual o sentido desse código? Você irá armazenar a entrada do usuário a partir da posição `posicao` do array. A palavra armazenada é a mesma, mas agora você tem o lixo que não foi inicializado do início do array, e para qual finalidade?

Para receber a entrada do usuário não tem truques, apenas

```
int main() 
{
    int posicao;
    char palavra_a[10], palavra_b[10];

    printf("Digite um nome: ");
    scanf("%s9", palavra_a);

    printf("Digite outro nome: ");
    scanf("%s9", palavra_b);

    printf("Digite uma posição: ");
    scanf("%d", &posicao);
}
```

Agora para inserir `palavra_b` dentro de `palavra_a`, vamos ter que brincar um pouco com as posições da memória:

```
void inserir(int posicao, char *palavra_a, char *palavra_b) 
{
    //messo o tamanho das palavras
    size_t tam_a = strlen(palavra_a);
    size_t tam_b = strlen(palavra_b);
    //crio um array com tamanho capaz de armazenar palavra a e b
    char nova_palavra[tam_a + tam_b + 1];

    //se a posição de inserção não for válida, atribuo um novo valor para posicao
    if (posicao > tam_a)
        posicao = tam_a;
    if (posicao < 0)
        posicao = 0;

    //copio a palavra_a para nova_palavra
    strcpy(nova_palavra, palavra_a);
    //copio a palavra_b para nova_palavra, a partir da posição de memória passado
    strcpy(&nova_palavra[posicao], palavra_b);
    //copio a parte de palavra_a que foi sobrescrevia para a posição de memória no final de nova_palavra
    strcpy(&nova_palavra[posicao + tam_b], &palavra_a[posicao]);

    printf("%s", nova_palavra);
}
```

Ou usando laços de repetição ao invés de `strcpy`

```
//copio palavra_a até posicao
for (i = 0; i < posicao; ++i)
    nova_palavra[i] = palavra_a[i];

//copio palavra_b e insiro em nova_palavra a partir de posicao
for (i = 0; i < tam_b; ++i)
    nova_palavra[posicao + i] = palavra_b[i];

//copio o restante de palavra_a e insiro a partir de posicao + tamanho da palavra_b
for (i = posicao; i < tam_a; ++i)
    nova_palavra[i + tam_b] = palavra_a[i];

//Adiciono o null terminator
nova_palavra[tam_a + tam_b] = '\0';
```

Para chamar a função, basta `inserir(posicao, palavra_a, palavra_b)`, não precisa enviar (e nem deve) posições do seu array.