# Fazer a concatenação e mostrar na tela

Tags: c

Não sei como fazer para imprimir o `strcat` na tela, não sei como fazer para concatenar na posição digitada no `scanf_s`.

```c
int main() {

    char string1[10], string2[10];
    int RU[1];
    char NomeSobrenome;

    printf("digite o Nome\n");
    gets_s(string1);

    printf("Digite o segundo nome\n");
    gets_s(string2);

    printf("Digite o ultimo digito do RU");
    scanf_s("%d", &RU[1]);

    strncat(string1, string2,RU[1]);

    NomeSobrenome = strncat;

    printf("%c", NomeSobrenome);

}
```

Comment: Qual é exatamente a dúvida? Quais são os dados que você insere e qual deveria ser o resultado? Ou ele nem está compilando, se não está qual o erro que você não compreende (coloque a mensagem neste caso)?

Answer (score 0):

`strncat` concatena uma string ao final da outra, não no meio.

Você pode utilizar `strcpy` para copiar a `string2` inteira para a posição de memória desejada, então basta manipular essa posição dentro da `string1`

```
printf("Digite o ultimo digito do RU\n");
scanf("%d", &i);

strcpy(&string1[i], string2);
printf("%s", string1);
```

Note que esse método não é seguro, pois `string1` armazena apenas 10 caracteres, o ideal seria criar uma string que pudesse armazenar tanto `string1` e `string2`

```
int main() {
    char string1[10], string2[10], string3[20];
    int i;

    printf("digite o Nome\n");
    scanf("%s9", string1);

    printf("Digite o segundo nome\n");
    scanf("%s9", string2);

    printf("Digite o ultimo digito do RU\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);

    strcpy(string3, string1);
    strcpy(&string3[i], string2);

    printf("%s", string3);
}
```

Comment: a ideia era digitar primeiro nome : fabio, digitar segundo nome: santos, depois dizer o ultimo digito: 3, por ultimo ficar san(fabio)tos

Comment: Imaginei. Outra pessoa vez exatamente a mesma pergunta. Veja se [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/396365/d%c3%bavidas-sobre-uso-de-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-em-c/396485#396485) te ajuda.